# how to detect commands in telegram bot (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

I'm developing a telegram bot

I can detect and use texts from users (`update.message.text`), what I want is, detect every command that user sends to bot.

is there a way to solve this?

- python 3.7
- python-telegram-bot module
- win 10

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

I just add `MessageHandler(Filters.command, kb_handler)`

```
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start),
                  MessageHandler(Filters.command, kb_handler)],
    states={},
    fallbacks=[]
)
```